# What is the scientific name of this flying insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It looks like some relative of dragon fly.

[image: pic1]

To give an idea about its size I picked it by its wings

[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

It had quite a flexible abdomen

[image: pic4]

I set it free after clicking the pics. I live in central India (If that matters)

Comment: Good on you for setting it free.

Comment: It seems that you were careful, but generally speaking try not to pick up insects by their wings, they are often the most fragile part and are one of the most essential for the insect's survival in many cases.

Comment: @ttbek OK I'll remember that!

Comment: @ttbek - that sounds nice in theory, but what else can you actually grab? Sure, for a hard beetle you can just grab damn thing by the body, but nearly everything else is too squishy for that.

Comment: @ttbek In general you are right, however dragonflies are about the only insects were it can't hurt to hold them by there wings (if done carefully off course).

Comment: Davor: I was wondering that I bit myself.... , but more in the sense of potential wing damage if one tries to hold on to somewhere else as they try to fly away.  The bodies are often not quite as squishy as you may imagine due the their exoskeletons, at least relative to the thin membrane that the wings often consist of.  Coyote Peterson often uses a special set of forceps for handling insects, and does grip them by the body this way, not a perfect reference but just from the top of my head for now.  
RHA:  Yeah, dragonflies are pretty badass like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This insect is, indeed, related to dragonflies. This is a **[damselfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damselfly)**.

Damselflies are Odonata insects from the Suborder Zygoptera. Unlike dragonflies (Suborder Anisoptera), damselflies fold their wings when resting. This is the most noticeable difference between damselflies and dragonflies:

[image]

Regarding your specimen, I'd say that it is *[Caconeura ramburi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caconeura_ramburi)*, the indian blue bambootail. Here is an image for comparison:

[image]

The site where I found that image, conveniently called [Odonata of India](http://www.indianodonata.org/#!/sp/312/Caconeura-ramburi), is a good source of information.